# Searching a nested List<T>

Tags: c#, generic-list, nested-generics

I have this data structure:

```
class Conference 
{
    private List<List<string>>_orgs;
    public List<List<string>> Orgs
    {
       set { _orgs = value; } get { return _orgs; }
    }
}
```

Data in this collection:

```
List<string> sublist = new List<string>();
sublist.Add("university");
sublist.Add("organization");

List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
list.Add(sublist);
```

Then:

```
Conference c = new Conference();
c.Orgs = list;
```

I have collection of conference objects:

```
List<Conference> listConferences = new List<Conference>(); 
listConferences.Add(c);
```

I want search a string like `"uni"` and find collection of conference have orgs like `"uni"`. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you should make some effort that the code actually compiles before posting a question.

Comment: Are you sure you've chosen the right data structure to use? This doesn't look meaningful IMO.

Comment: i have xml file like this: `<conference><org code "a">university</org><org code "b">123987Bn</org><org code "a">organization</org><org code "b">465465465sf</org><conference/>` i select abouve structure for save this data from xml file.save org name and number.What is your recommendation for the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var selection = listConferences
                .Where(x => x.Orgs.SelectMany(y => y).Any(y => y.Contains("uni")))
                .ToList();
```

Note:

the trailing `ToList()` might not be necessary depending on your needs (e.g. if you iterate selection only once you can skip it).

Comment: thank u. but this code return result when search for example "university". i want search with like condition

Comment: @TAIT: yes, my fault sorry. I forgot one piece of code. Check my edit ;)

Comment: really great! :) thank you so much.   Search over 400,000 records in less time and get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, below;
instead of third one, you may use your own conference list. you can now use similar to like keyword.

```
List<string> first = new List<string>();
            first.Add("University");
            first.Add("Standard");

            List<List<string>> second = new List<List<string>>();
            second.Add(first);

            List<List<List<string>>> third = new List<List<List<string>>>();
            third.Add(second);

            var e = third.Find(delegate(List<List<string>> r) 
                        { 
                            bool isValid = false; 
                            if(r.Count > 0)
                            { 
                                foreach(List<string> s in r)
                                { 
                                    if(s.Count > 0 ) 
                                    { 
                                        isValid = s.FindAll(delegate(string t){ return t.StartsWith("uni", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);}).Count > 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return isValid;
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Done, one more workout using linq. You should be feeling comfortable with this:

```
var univ = from p in c.Orgs
                       select p.FindAll(r => r.FindAll(s => s.StartsWith("univ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```